# div position issue in clone jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Please see my fiddle location.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ph73ezvy/2/)

I have `div` called "**size-drop-center**", which is placed in a common place. Dynamically rows will be added by clicking the add button. In that case the div position is not changed, it displayed at the end of last row.  I want this div will be displayed in below the each row. Please see my image screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You jsfiddle link and question does not seem to be relevant. Could you please check and update question.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar the JSFiddle and question are relevant. Akash can you be a bit more clear on what you're trying to achieve? Forgive me for not understanding your English.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have your `.size-drop-center` in a "common" place, and your JS simply toggles that element, then it will appear in its place of origin.

From my understanding, to get this appear "in the relevant row", you could clone the .size-drop-center into the row and toggle from there.

See this updated fiddle for a working example using existing code: http://jsfiddle.net/ph73ezvy/4/

```
$(".arrow_text img").click(function(){
  var row = $(this).parents('.text_flied');
  var sizeDrop = row.find('.size-drop-center')

  if (!sizeDrop.length) {
    sizeDrop = $('#size-drop-center').clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo(row);
  }

  sizeDrop.length && sizeDrop.toggle();
});
```

All I've done is given the common `.size-drop-center` an `id` attribute to allow a unique global reference and amended your `click` handler to append the `#size-drop-center` **to the relevant row**, if one doesn't already exist, and then toggle it.

Of course, we remove the `id` attribute from the cloned element since these are referenced uniquely.

Hope this helps.